# Android popupMenu not displaying items

Tags: android, popupmenu

I want to make a popup menu, without actionbar. It works fine, but displaying just a black square, and the items are visible only on touch.
I tried a lot of different codes but nothing worked.. Any suggestions please?`

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    settButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moresett);
    settButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(Test.this, R.style.PopupMenu);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, settButton);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sett_menu, popup.getMenu());

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.curr_sett:
                            //some code
                            return true;
                        case R.id.change_sett:
                            //some code
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

`
R.menu.sett_menu:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>


<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/curr_sett"
    android:title="Current Settings"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/change_sett"
    android:title="Change Settings"></item>
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MDm4.png)

Answer (score 0):

In you activity's layout file check this attribute in your Toolbar

```
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I don't use toolbar and actionbar. However I tried it but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found the problem (I'm just saying, for future similar problems..):

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

I deleted this, and everything work properly now! Hope this will help others! :)